# scanner file to array list reading font

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, tostring

I am trying to read from a file and print the average word length for the ArrayList.  When I print or get the average of the list was populated with the font and other material from the .txt file.

I have already created a file reader and here is the code for populating the ArrayList from file:

```
    String homedir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    System.out.println("homedir = " + homedir);
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(new File(homedir));
    jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println("File read = " + file);
    ArrayList<String> words = copyWords(scanner);
    return words;
```

the copyWords method

```
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        words.add(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
    }
    return words;
```

I understand that I need to convert it via toString() but how would I do that.  I tried to do Arrays.toString(words) but that did not work.  Would I have to write the copyWords method using toString() when I add the words?

I guess I am just confused about where my @Override needs to go if anywhere.  I tried to search but don't understand how to get what I find to solve my problem.

Comment: .txt files shouldn't have font information, so your statement about this has me greatly confused. Please post more information about the file. You're not saving it using wordpad are you?

Comment: And this: `"I understand that I need to convert it via toString()"` doesn't make sense. What String output are you trying to achieve? Most of the time you *wouldn't* use ArrayList's toString() except if you want your words in the output that it produces. Else you'll likely need to iterate through the list, perhaps populating a StringBuilder, but how? that will depend on what you're trying to get.

Comment: I figured it out.  It wss because the files were saving as .rtf not .txt so they were using font.  I didn't think of it until you said ".txt files shouldn't have font"